# Using Interrupt to Transmit via USART on AVR MCU

Tags: c, interrupt, avr, usart

I believe I understand how to use interrupts to receive serial data on UART of an ATmega328p, but I don't understand the mechanics of how to transmit data.

Here is a basic program that I want to use to transmit the character string "hello" using interrupts to drive transmission.  I understand that the character 'o' will likely be transmitted twice, and I am ok with that.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>
#define F_CPU 16000000UL
#define BAUD 19200
#define DOUBLE_SPEED 1

void initUART(unsigned int baud, unsigned int speed);

volatile uint8_t charIndex = 0;
volatile unsigned char command[5] = "hello";

int main(void)
{
    //initialize UART
    initUART(BAUD, DOUBLE_SPEED);

    sei();

    //What do I put here to initiate transmission of character string command?
    //Is this even correct?
    UDR0 = command[0];

    while(1)
    { 

    }   
}

ISR(USART_TX_vect) 
{
   // Transmit complete interrupt triggered
    if (charIndex >= 4) 
    {
        //Reach the end of command, end transmission
        return; 
    }
    //transmit the first char or byte
    UDR0 = command[charIndex];
    //Step to the next place of the command
    charIndex++; 
}

void initUART(unsigned int baud, unsigned int speed)
{
    unsigned int ubrr;

    if(speed)
    {
        //double rate mode
        ubrr = F_CPU/8/baud-1;
        //set double speed mode
        UCSR0A = (speed << U2X0);
    }
    else
    {
        //normal rate mode
        ubrr = F_CPU/16/baud-1;
    }

    //set the baud rate
    UBRR0H = (unsigned char)(ubrr >> 8);
    UBRR0L = (unsigned char)(ubrr);

    //enable Tx and Rx pins on MCU
    UCSR0B = (1 << RXEN0) | (1 << TXEN0);

    //enable transmit interrupt
    UCSR0B = (1 << TXCIE0);

    //set control bits, 8 bit char, 0 stop, no parity
    UCSR0C = (1 <<UCSZ00) | (1 <<UCSZ01);
}
```

My understanding is that if I wrote the first character to UDR0 (as I did in main()), this would then trigger a Transmit Complete Interrupt, and then the next byte would be transmitted via the ISR.  This does not seem to work.

The code shown here compiles using gcc.  Can someone offer an explanation?

Comment: When you are done transmitting, I believe you will have to disable the USART's TX interrupt to avoid getting stuck in it forever.  And similarly, you should only enable the interrupt when there is data to send.  But I am not sure if that would solve your current problem.  What is your problem, specifically?  Do you see any bytes transmitted on TX or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key thing to understand is that the USART has 2 separate hardware registers that are used in the data transmission: `UDRn` and the `Transmit Shift Register`, which I'll just call `TSR` from now on.

When you write data to `UDRn`, assuming no tx is in progress, it'll get moved to the `TSR` immediately and the UDRE irq fires to tell you that the `UDRn` register is "empty". Note that at this point the transmission has just started, but the point is that you can already write the next byte to `UDRn`.

When the byte has been fully transmitted, the next byte is moved from `UDRn` to `TSR` and `UDRE` fires again. So, you can write the next byte to `UDRn` and so on.

You must only write data to the `UDRn` when it is "empty", otherwise you'll overwrite the byte it's currently storing and pending transmission.

In practice, you don't usually mind about the `TXC` irq, you want to work with the `UDRE` to feed more data to the USART module.

The `TXC` irq, however, is useful if you need to perform some operation when the transmission has actually completed. A common example when dealing with RS485 is to disable the transmitter once you're done sending data and possibly re-enable the receiver that you could have disabled to avoid echo.

**Regarding your code**

Your main issue is that you're setting `UCSR0B` 2 times in `initUART()` and the second write clears the bits you just set, so it's disabling the transmitter. You want to set all bits in one go, or use a `|=` on the second statement.

Comment: Thanks, I didn't see that I set UCSR0B twice.  When I get home I'll change that.  I'll also spend time thinking Bout your other comments.  Thank you.

Comment: Zmaster, I corrected the USART initialization...that makes a huge difference.  Thanks for the catch.  I also added code to main() to transmit the first character only after knowing the UDRE0 register was empty.  while( !(UCSR0A & (1 << UDRE0)) ) {};  UDR0 = command[0];  After I did this, "hello" was printed to my terminal emulator.  Thank you.

Comment: Good. To simplify things, I would just prepare the buffer and index variable, then enable the UDRE interrupt and let the ISR write all the bytes (including the first one). It will fire as soon as you enable it, because the UDRn register is initially empty, and then fire again when UDRn can be written with the next byte. When the buffer is fully sent, you need to disable the interrupt or it'll keep firing.